# Display dynamic blocks instead of static in front page?

Tags: drupal-6, content-type

I have a site in which the front page contains the 4 blocks of text, basically a small introductory boxes. Curently these boxes contain the static data. What I want now is to convert these boxes to content and can change their boxes from admin. Basically making site more user friendly. The boxes contain title , a small thumbnail and small description. I have created a content type in which I have title field , body field and 1 image attached option. Can I show them the way I want without using views.

```
                        <?php if($messages) print $messages; ?>
                        <div class="content_left">
                        <div class="block1">
                            <h4 class="title-storefront">Gorgeous Storefront</h4>
                                Each Shopify store comes with a variety of beautiful themes to choose from.Each Shopify store comes with a variety of beautiful themes to choose from.Each Shopify store comes with a variety of beautiful themes to choose from.Each Shopify store comes with a variety of beautiful themes to choose from.Each Shopify store comes with a variety of beautiful themes to choose from.</div>
                            <div class="block1">
                            <h4 class="title-customizable">100% Customizable</h4>
                                Use your own HTML &amp; CSS and have complete control over the look and feel of your online store.Use your own HTML &amp; CSS and have complete control over the look and feel of your online store.Use your own HTML &amp; CSS and have complete control over the look and feel of your online store.Use your own HTML &amp; CSS and have complete control over the look and feel of your online store.
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content_right">
                            <div class="block1">
                            <h4 class="title-shoppingcart">Shopping Cart</h4>
                                Your online store will have its own shopping cart and streamlined checkout.Your online store will have its own shopping cart and streamlined checkout.Your online store will have its own shopping cart and streamlined checkout.Your online store will have its own shopping cart and streamlined checkout.Your online store will have its own shopping cart and streamlined checkout.
                        </div>
                            <div class="block1">
                            <h4 class="title-secure">Super Secure</h4>
                                 We have a dedicated team of security experts that make sure your e-commerce site is as secure as possible.We have a dedicated team of security experts that make sure your e-commerce site is as secure as possible.We have a dedicated team of security experts that make sure your e-commerce site is as secure as possible.We have a dedicated team of security experts that make sure your e-commerce site is as secure as possible.
                        </div>
                        </div>
                      </div> <!-- /#content-area -->
```

How can I print title, image and description of a content separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, create Blocks for the content. You may need to add regions in your theme, to which you can then assign your blocks. If you're looking to add lists of nodes in the blocks, though, Views is the way to go. If you can explain why you're avoiding Views, perhaps others will be able to advise an alternative.